# Yaml, Is there any method to add some character after call the anchor

Tags: python, yaml

For example

My yaml file(Test.yml):

```
fruit  : &apple Apple
fruits : *apple , Pineapple
```

Python code

```
import yaml

with open('Test.yml', 'r') as f:
     data = yaml.safe_load(f)

print(data['fruits'])
```

Output get error

```
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
expected <block end>, but found ','
```

My expected output is

```
Apple, Pineapple
```

Comment: Hi, can you flesh out the question a little more, add some code we can run to replicate the issue you are having: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Tzane OK, thx for your advise I edit already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your `fruits` be a sequence:

```yaml
fruit: &apple Apple
fruits: [*apple, pineapple]
```

However you can not concatenate the scalar value `Apple` to other values, because YAML is a pure data serialization language and cannot *process* data in any way.

Comment: Hi flyx, thanks for your reply. So, if i want to get the value in str form, I can only get the value in list form first and join by myself?

Comment: Well you can always use a local tag like this: `fruits: !concat [*apple, pineapple]` You can then register a custom constructor for this tag which does the concatenation. However I do not recommend this – YAML is not a data processor and should not be used as such. Most tools that take complex YAML as input are providing some kind of templating (e.g. Jinja) for preprocessing to facilitate this instead.